# Vue2 is successful in writing like this,but using vue3 will prompt the following questions

Tags: vuejs3

Vue2 is successful in writing like this,but using vue3 will prompt the following questions.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBanner' of undefined
at _callee$ (Banner.vue?40cf:46)
at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:293)
at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:118)
at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21)
at Proxy.getBanner (Banner.vue?40cf:46)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like `this.$api` is undefined. Where are you setting that?

Comment: main.js，I coded the following.

import api from "./axios/index.js"
createApp(App).config.globalProperties.$api=api;

Comment: And my method is the following:`async getBanner() {
      try {
        let res = await this.$api.getBanner()
        if (res.status === 200 && res.statusText === "OK") {
          this.banners = res.data.banners
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }`

Comment: What are the contents of `axios/index.js`?

Comment: index.js.`import instance from "./instance"    export const getBanner = () => instance.get("/banner",{})`

Comment: instance.js`import axios from "axios"
import config from "./config"

const instance = axios.create({
  timeout: 5000,
  baseURL: config.base_url,
  withCredentials: true 
})

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    return config
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.error(error)
  }
)


instance.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  },
  error => {

  }
)

export default instance`

Comment: config.js`let base_url = ""

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  base_url = "http://localhost:3000"
}
export default { base_url }`